# Regresson on 3d tabular data

Tags: regression, machine-learning

There is a dataset, where each Y depends on separate table :

[image]

Each table consists of the same set of columns, but the number of rows may vary.
Features in tables are both numerical and categorical (both nominal and ordinal).
Numerical features may have a heavy-tailed distributions.

I need to build a regression model, which predicts Y numerical value by table.

What is the common name of this task?
What are the methods for solving this type of problem?

Comment: It sounds like either a different regression for each Y, or else multivariate regression. You can read about these in various threads on here (and in other places) and see if one of them is what you want.  If not, you can let us know.

Comment: @PeterFlom y is one value like in ordinary regression, but samples are tables, not rows